# HostListener on outside click Angular 6

Tags: angular

This is my way to open a popover:

```html
<div>
  <a (click)="trigger = true">
    <div>
      <i class="pe-7s-file"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div popover clickOutside (clickOutside)="console.log('Outside')" *ngIf="trigger==true">
    <p>Hello Popover</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click on first div it prints (outside) in my console, I want to open the popover at first time without any message on console, and when I click outside popover div the console should print.

This is my hostlistener:

```ts
@Directive({
    selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {

    constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) { }

    @Output('clickOutside') clickOutside: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
    onMouseEnter(targetElement) {
        const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
        if (!clickedInside) {
            this.clickOutside.emit(null);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you explain your end goal here ? If you mean "popover" like a modal or a tooltip, maybe you should use the CDK and its `OverlayModule` instead of directives.

Comment: (I'm telling you that because overlays have a very easy way to listen for click events in the backdrop)

Comment: That `@HostListener` works ?

Comment: Will that delegate event hook to document and filter out by target??? Or will apply to every document onclicks ? Or it is not that "host" listener at all but rather event listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure about what you try to achieve so far. So base on my interpretation i have modify your code as following :

**html**

```
<div>
    <a (click)="displayPopover()">
        <div>
            my content outside
        </div>
    </a>
    <ng-container *ngIf="isDisplay">
      <div clickOutside (clickOutside)="myHandler()" style="border: 1px solid black">
          <p>Click me, nothing will happen</p>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

**component ts for sample only :**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  isDisplay: boolean = false;
  myHandler() {
    console.log('click outside');
    this.isDisplay = false;
  }

  displayPopover() {
    this.isDisplay = true;
  }
}
```

**directive :**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    @Output('clickOutside') clickOutside: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();
    squareMatrix: {
      x1: number,
      y1: number,
      x2: number,
      y2: number
    };
    sub: Subscription;
    constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        /**
         * Populate current square x,y position.
         */
        this.populateMatrix();
        // Timeout is here to ignore first click. Not right way but do the job.
        setTimeout(() => {
        this.sub = fromEvent(window, 'click').subscribe((e: MouseEvent) => {
            if(!this.checkIfClickOnSquare(e.clientX, e.clientY)) {
              this.clickOutside.emit();
            }
        });
        },100); 
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
      if(this.sub) {
        //Don't forget to unsubscribe.
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
      }
    }

    private populateMatrix() {
      const {x, y, width, height} = this._elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();

      this.squareMatrix = {
        x1 : x,
        y1: y,
        x2: x + width,
        y2: y + height
      };
    }

    private checkIfClickOnSquare(currentX, currentY): boolean {
      return (
          currentX > this.squareMatrix.x1 &&
          currentX < this.squareMatrix.x2 && 
          currentY > this.squareMatrix.y1 && 
          currentY < this.squareMatrix.y2
        );
    }
}
```

**Explication :**
I have create square matrix to have point reference of the actual drawed Popover. base on this square, on each click trigger by document, i check if current x,y cursor is inside or outside of current DOMElement.

To prevent initial click i have added timeout before to bind the event. Is not right way to do it bit is doing the job.

you can look on the [live sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjbvyr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fclick-outside.directive.ts) if you prefer.

Comment: hey @Yanis-git, I am stuck on a similar problem. I wanted to know if you found a better approach to ignore the first click?

Comment: hi Javan, what you means by ignoring the first click ? could you provide me a sample with expected user flow ?